# Can't create thumbnail with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I can not create a preview for a video with 4k resolution. Setting: docker image ubuntu 16.04

`ffmpeg -i file.MOV -ss 00:00:00 -vframes 1 thumbnail.png`

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Killed
```

Comment: Share full log of `ffmpeg -i file.MOV -vframes 1 thumbnail.png -v 48`